# Migrated answers are shown as having been converted to comments

Tags: bug, migration, deleted-answers

Seems like something has gone wrong recently with the banner displayed on answers that get automatically deleted on the source site when their question is migrated to another site. See [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/255072/31394) (link is to a migration stub on Sci-Fi & Fantasy, although it will redirect to a link on Literature for people without sufficient rep/diamonds):

[image: screenshot of the migration stub page showing the bug]

The answer's [post timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/255074/timeline) correctly shows that it was migrated, not converted to a comment, but the banner visible on the post itself says "deleted and converted to a comment".

I guess this is a bug related to an exception case that someone forgot to account for, like it's set to display "deleted and converted to a comment" *unless* blah blah blah, and there's not enough possibilities included in that "blah blah blah".